# Audacity crashes after recording 10s or so of sound

Tags: audio

I'm experimenting with recording sound using the Pi and a USB microphone.

I can record long samples using `arecord` from the command line but when I use Audacity I get frequent bus errors, usually after 10 seconds or so of recording.

I've changed the sound quality down to 22 KHz to lighten the load on the CPU, but this doesn't seem to affect the crashing.

Here's the log info from kern.log:

```
Feb 12 13:27:15 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6207.394332] Alignment trap: not handling instruction ece77a01 at [<00393db0>]
Feb 12 13:27:15 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6207.394367] Unhandled fault: alignment exception (0x811) at 0xb2805c72
```

Comment: I've had better success and reliability at 48 kHz. This might seem unintuitive, and it may depend on the sound card, but see if it helps.

Comment: I've tried this and it does seem more reliable at 44 kHz. I've got a feeling I also changed some other settings a while back (from the defaults) so I'll try a few more options and report back.